# if (!localplayer) not doing anything

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a multiplayer dodgeball game and every time I start up a host and a client, only one of the players can move.[image]

I want the players to move independently. Here is my (updated) code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;
public class Script4Network : NetworkBehaviour
{

// Use this for initialization
void Start() {
if (!isLocalPlayer)
    {

        gameObject.GetComponent<FirstPersonController>().enabled = false;
        gameObject.GetComponent<throwing>().enabled = false;
        gameObject.GetComponent<HeadBob>().enabled = false;
        // gameObject.GetComponent<Camera>().enabled = false;
    }
}

void Update()
{

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an answer because I've been out of unity for too long, but just so you know:

```
void Update()
{
    if (!isLocalPlayer)
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

Does nothing at all.   It's the same thing as:

```
void Update()
{
    if (!isLocalPlayer)
    {
        return;
    }
    return;
}
```

Because every function returns at the end.  So if we're not local, then return immediately.  Otherwise, return immediately.  You need some way to disable the input controls -- maybe in `Start()` find the input controls component and disable if `!isLocalPlayer`.

Comment: I just tried the code above, I disabled the script that controls input as well as other scripts on the player. The result is that they are independent, but only one of them can move.